# Disappearing buttons in ckeditor while using two plugins

Tags: plugins, widget, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have installed widget plugin and did copy/paste of the code from [here](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/widget_sdk_tutorial_1)

Then, I have installed following plugin: [HTMLButtonsPlugin](http://alfonsoml.blogspot.com.es/2012/05/creating-button-to-insert-some-html-in.html)

The problem is that when both of them are enabled, I can see the buttons only of the first of the plugins listed in my config.js.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: The buttons have the same name?

Comment: no, can you se ethem having same name?:)

Comment: Maybe you changed the name or forgot to change it when doing copy&paste ;). Anyway, another idea - you set `config.extraPlugins` twice.

Comment: yes I did. I can see I can use the [ ] when setting up the plugins, but then why other plugins can be loaded by using config.extraPlugins multiple times but not the buttons

Comment: `config.extraPlugins` is only a property, so you set it twice only the second value will count. This is how it works in JavaScript.